# Ubuntu 18.10 clean. Programs not starting

Tags: 18.10

18.10 clean fresh install.

After setup all, some of the programs won't start.
An example is atom.io. I click on icon nothing happens. I try to run in a terminal with sudo and this is output in a terminal:

```
/usr/bin/atom: line 157: 10967 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) nohup "$ATOM_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out" 2>&1
```

And there is no any GUI or anything.

2nd is gnome-tweak.

```
WARNING : Shell not installed or running
WARNING : Error detecting shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_shell_extensions.py", line 217, in __init__
    raise Exception("Shell not running or DBus service not available")
Exception: Shell not running or DBus service not available
WARNING : Shell not running
NoneType: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/app.py", line 30, in do_activate
    self.win = Window(self, model)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweakview.py", line 38, in __init__
    self._model.load_tweaks(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweakmodel.py", line 104, in load_tweaks
    mods = __import__("gtweak.tweaks", globals(), locals(), tweak_files, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_general.py", line 14, in <module>
    _shell_not_ubuntu = _shell.mode != 'ubuntu'
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mode'
```

For now only this 2 not working. When crash report shows it list sh... loads of all things that I reported.
I try to reinstall 2 times =(

Any words of wisdom?

Comment: Are you running 64 bit or 32 bit Ubuntu?

Comment: 64
:uname -a
Linux lateralus 4.18.0-10-generic #11-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 11 15:13:55 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Have you selected "Ubuntu" at the login screen cog wheel icon? Does everything else seem to run OK? Do desktop icons appear? Do you have a clock in the centter of the top panel? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Ubuntu Budgie 18.10. All pre-installed programs are working fine. Extra budgie applets, themes and all another are ok, working fine. Chromium, FileZilla, Pidgin, VeraCrypt, all LibreOffice... All OK...
When I click, or terminal run, icon show itself on a plank bar. And that is far as it goes. After 1 min, or so, crash report. 
Have a clock in center =)

Answer (score 3):

I've had exactly the same problem. It turns out it is an [issue](https://github.com/atom/atom/pull/18012) with electron and glibc 2.28.

It is fixed in the upcoming Atom release (v1.32). You can install a beta with the fix merged from their [GitHub release page](https://github.com/atom/atom/releases) or wait until the proper release.

Comment: can confirm 1.32 build works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Chrome Remote Desktop. I was able to kill it by switching to command line (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>)  and removing it.
  `sudo apt-get autoremove chrome-remote-desktop`

You can switch back with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>